# Rails Update Column 1 where Value, Update Column 2 where Value in single query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can work on the following code:

```
Contact.where(tag1: tag_ids).update_all(tag1: nil)
Contact.where(tag2: tag_ids).update_all(tag2: nil)
```

Is it possible to execute a certain query in rails where it needs to update specific column if its value satisfied, and/or update another column if its value is also satisfied. Sorry for bad explanation, please refer to code above.

Above code can do exactly what I want, but in case there is a better way or single-line code to this?

Comment: The docs say you can. Not sure where your problem lies. https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible. Even you can, the columns will also be fixed, ugly sql, very easy to get wrong.

Because the sql query need specific columns, if some rows with `tag1` or `tag2` query match, you also can't differentiate them(which field satisfy), then you can't decide which column to set to nil.

But you can simplify to

```
['tag1', 'tag2'].map {|column| Contact.where(column.to_sym => tag_ids).update_all(column.to_sym => nil) }
```

And you can add more column to the array, like ['tag1', 'tag2', tag3'].

Some complexity is necessary.

Comment: Oneliner against single query I guess )

Comment: it's also ok to add the `do end block`, it's just some preference. The main reason is that it's array now, only need to add elements to the array. no need to add repetition code. Actually i also don't like oneline, but it's more convenience to paste it here.

Comment: How do you thinks it scales? 1M records table doing and 'select IN' and than update_all per each element in array.

Comment: I don't say you wrong, I say that it is easy to add elements to array and one year later it could become a bottleneck :)

Comment: um, this is a classics problem, code vs speed, it depends on the detailed situation. i think just let the user to make the choice.

Comment: Thank you @seaify-Freelancer. This is the method I used instead. But I skipped `update_all` in rails as it locks out users who access the table when I need to update 1M records. I mean, this might be unusual to update large records, but we managed to set it by batch of 50k instead of update_all. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(<<-EOQ)
UPDATE contacts
SET tag1 = ( CASE 
 WHEN tag1 IN (#{tag_ids.join(',')) THEN NULL
 ELSE -1
 END),
tag2 = ( CASE
 WHEN tag2 IN (#{tag_ids.join(',')) THEN NULL
 ELSE -1
 END)
EOQ
```

Not so pretty :)